# Angularjs click row if the data is available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to JavaScript so I am not sure what is possible. I am using AngularJS as my frontend application. 
I've a clickable table(rows) its pretty much a table inside a table (collapisble table)

I'm trying to click the first row of the table if the data is available so I wrote this function

```
 $scope.clicker = function(){
    if (!$scope.first || !$scope.second){
         setTimeout($scope.clicker, 500)
       } 
    $(".clickableRow").first().click()
  }
```

This pretty much checks if the values first and second is not null, if not then click the first row. This WOULD work sometimes but almost every time I get this error '

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

I am not sure what this means. Any help would be nice.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to click on the first row? There's almost definitely a better way to do what ever it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Kolby So I've a collapisble table (http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/VGgbq/) Something like this. I want to automatically click on the first row of the table so it would  collapse the first row

Comment: So why not call selectTableRow() instead of doing the click?

Comment: How do i check if the data is there before collapsing it? Should i just do  the same check i did here like if ( not null) then call?

Comment: when would $scope.clicker be called? I don't see it in your fiddle.

Comment: @Kolby Thanks for the help. here is what I have (http://pastebin.com/10gaML80)

Comment: I have 3 http requests, I am trying to call it after all of them are done pretty much

Comment: What do you mean by done? Do you want this $scope.clicker to run after the table and data has been loaded, or is it after a click or some other event?

Comment: I think I see what you want now. You just want to check that $scope.browserKPI and $scope.serverKPI has been set after their $http request has finished. For this you can use `$q.all()` I'll make an answer showing how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$q.all` you can pass in multiple `$http` requests in an array.
You can use `.then` on the `q.all()` method and get a callback when they're all done.

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() {
        return $route.current;
    },
    function(newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            $scope.url = newValue.$$route.originalPath;

            if($scope.url == '/loadTestForm') return;

            $scope.neustaridParam = newValue.params.neustarid;
            $q.all([
                $http.get('/corecase/browserKPI/'+$scope.neustaridParam).success(function(response){
                    $scope.browserKPI = response;
                }),
                $http.get('/corecase/serverKPI/'+$scope.neustaridParam).success(function(response){
                        $scope.serverKPI = response;
                }),
                $http.get('/corecase/info/'+$scope.neustaridParam).success(function(response){
                        $scope.corecaseinfo = response;
                })
            ]).then(function(){
                $scope.selectTableRow(0, 1000); //I'd advise not hardcoding the first row's data here. You can do something like this instead: $scope.storeDataModel.storedata[0].id, scope.storeDataModel.storedata[0].storeId
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only purpose behind the click event is to show or hide then you can potentially skip the click event all together.  Put a "ng-show" in your tr (or any other element you want to show) and simply set a scoped variable equal to whatever is referencing your data.  If you have data then your ng-show will be true and it will show. This is also assuming that your data is undefined or null until it is available, if not just set it to false.

```
     In view:
    <tr ng-show="checkData"></tr> 

    In controller:
    $scope.checkData = data;
```